# Unable to start a flume-ng agent

Tags: flume

I am trying to get started with flume-ng and following user guide at: http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

I am running this command after setting up an in-memory agent as a simple test:

```
flume-ng agent -c /usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf -f /usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf/flume-netcat.conf -n a1
```

I get the following output which obviously does not indicate that it has started. 
Can someone tell me what's going on. I searched online but could not find much.

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/local/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Excluding /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar from classpath
+ exec /Library/Java/Home/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf:/usr/local/Cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../conf:/Library/Java/Home/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/..:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../hadoop-core-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.1/libexec/bin/../lib/native/Mac_OS_X-x86_64-64 org.apache.flume.node.Application -f /usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf/flume-netcat.conf -n a1
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your config file? (/usr/local/cellar/flume-ng/1.2.0-cdh4.1.0/libexec/conf/flume-netcat.conf)

Answer (score 0):

The conf file was setup incorrectly. Followed the tutorial once again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

setup conf file correctly & use flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  jar file to get result